# Does xlib have an active window event?

Tags: c, linux, xlib, xorg

I am trying to write a program that tracks when the active window changes using Xlib.  I am have trouble figuring out the best way to do this.  These are my ideas so far:

- Every second use _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW to get the active window and if it has changed then running the related code for the event.
- Get a list of all windows and listen to their focus in event.  I would have to figure out how to keep an up to date list of open windows though.

Is their an easier/better way?  I am new to programming with Xlib.

Comment: Listening to all focus events plus registering all the handlers for all the windows seems extremely expensive. I wonder if, in fact, listening to PointerMove in general and then calling `XGetInputFocus()` from the event handler to find out who has it when moved would be less overhead. How realtime does this have to be ? If the answer to that is "a sec is fine" then the polling method seems best.

Comment: It doesn't have to be real time, with in a couple of seconds would be okay.  I will give my first method a try. Thanks FrankH.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Python implementation of what @alanc proposed.

```
import Xlib
import Xlib.display

disp = Xlib.display.Display()
root = disp.screen().root

NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW = disp.intern_atom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW')
NET_WM_NAME = disp.intern_atom('_NET_WM_NAME')

last_seen = {'xid': None}
def get_active_window():
    window_id = root.get_full_property(NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW,
                                       Xlib.X.AnyPropertyType).value[0]

    focus_changed = (window_id != last_seen['xid'])
    last_seen['xid'] = window_id

    return window_id, focus_changed

def get_window_name(window_id):
    try:
        window_obj = disp.create_resource_object('window', window_id)
        window_name = window_obj.get_full_property(NET_WM_NAME, 0).value
    except Xlib.error.XError:
        window_name = None

    return window_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.change_attributes(event_mask=Xlib.X.PropertyChangeMask)
    while True:
        win, changed = get_active_window()
        if changed:
            print(get_window_name(win))

        while True:
            event = disp.next_event()
            if (event.type == Xlib.X.PropertyNotify and
                    event.atom == NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW):
                break
```

The more fully-commented version I wrote as an example for someone is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ssokolow/e7c9aae63fb7973e4d64cff969a78ae8).

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just select `PropertyChange` on the root window to get sent `PropertyNotify` events when any property is updated and then check each event to see if it was for `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`?

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking for "active windows change event grabber" as well. What I use in mean time (and might be helpful for you) is combination of [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) and [xwininfo](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xwininfo.1.html).

```
xwininfo -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)"
```

Comment: this gets the active window information, but how does it help in registering an event handler?

Comment: Once again, this is not a 'C' answer.  And coming from someone with 10.7k?!?  Stackoverflow, you are killing yourself.  You use to be so good, now you've lost the plot.