# How to monitor active window changes using xcb?

Tags: c, x11, xcb, ewmh

I'm trying to find a way to monitor when the `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` property changes. Right now I'm polling every 1 second to update the current active window. I know that there's a way to get events about this, I've seen references to it, but I can't seem to find any code (that I can understand) that explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `PropertyChange` mask on root window you'll start getting `PropertyNotify` events to your code. See example in my answer here: [Linux get notification on focused gui window change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840459/linux-get-notification-on-focused-gui-window-change/19847998#19847998)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm still having trouble getting it right. Here's what I got so far. https://pastebin.com/p1p3PxRP this doesn't work tho, if I switch windows nothing happens to my output

Comment: your code looks good in general ( though I'm not very familiar with xcb api )