# How to subscribe to X11 events in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, x11, xlib

I tried mimicking [this Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262413/does-xlib-have-an-active-window-event) in Haskell using [XMonad's X11 library](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.13/X11-1.10.3/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Window.html), but unfortunately my code just hangs and does not react when I trigger events by switching focused windows:

```hs
disp <- X11.openDisplay ""
let root = X11.defaultRootWindow disp
X11.allocaSetWindowAttributes $ \swaPtr ->
    X11.changeWindowAttributes disp root X11.propertyChangeMask swaPtr
allocaXEvent $ \e -> nextEvent disp e
```

This code never terminates, but the Python equivalent normally catches X events. What is wrong here?

Comment: My X11-fu is very rusty, but I guess you need to use `set_event_mask :: Ptr SetWindowAttributes -> EventMask -> IO ()` to set the `propertyChangeMask` bit. Then, you must call `X11.changeWindowAttributes disp root X11.cWEventMask swaPtr`. It is very unfortunate that the two `Mask`s (attribute and event masks) have the same Haskell type, which misled you -- a type error would have helped here.

Comment: Okay Chi, it worked, many thanks for finding this. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the python code you linked, the Haskell X11 library from XMonad mimics the C library closely. What we want to do here is:

- Call `changeWindowAttributes` specifying the attribute(s) we want to change. Here we want to specify the "event mask" attribute.
- Before that call, write inside `swaPtr` the actual event mask we want to set, using `set_event_mask :: Ptr SetWindowAttributes -> EventMask -> IO ()`.

The final code should read like:

```
X11.allocaSetWindowAttributes $ \swaPtr ->
    X11.set_event_mask swaPtr X11.propertyChangeMask
    X11.changeWindowAttributes disp root X11.cWEventMask swaPtr
```

Minor digression: it is very unfortunate that `X11.propertyChangeMask` and `X11.cWEventMask` have the same type in C, and further also have the same type in Haskell. A `newtype` wrapper here would have prevented your original code, that tries to pass an event mask as an attribute mask. Arguably, even in C one would have used a lightweight `struct EventMask { unsigned long em; }` to prevent similar type confusion. For some reason (which I can't fathom), C libraries often abstain to pass structs as parameters, as if they still wanted to be compatible with pre-ISO, pre-ANSI, K&R C, even when they are created in much more modern times.